# When to clear out Viewbag on a redirect with toastr

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, toastr

I'm using toastr to display messages after an action is performed in an MVC application.  It displays the message correctly, the problem is that it shows it again if someone comes back to the page it was displayed on.  I'm using the following code:

```
    $(document).ready(function () {
        var msg = "@ViewBag.Message";
        if (msg != "") {
            toastr["success"](msg);
        }
    });
```

So from the page I'm firing an AJAX call and in the success callback redirecting the page to it's original action, and setting the ViewBag.message when I do.  The problem is that if someone navigates off the page, and then clicks back to it, the message displays again.  I've tried clearing the ViewBag in a couple of different places but it either clears the message entirely or doesn't work.

Comment: Shouldn't the toastr be on an event handler (user action event) rather than on document ready?

Comment: It is not ViewBag, but the js code generated using the view bag (check the view source).

Comment: I don't have it on an event handler because it's supposed to pop after a window reload.

Comment: Why not have the message appear before the redirect?

Comment: Because the message being passed to the toastr is in the loading event of the view.

Comment: you can store the value of message of '@ViewBag.message' in js variable after show toast then clear your variable. Hope this will help